# OpenCV Haar feature detection, limited to Camshift tracked region

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

Working from a video file, I scan through the video frame by frame until I find a face using the OpenCV Haar frontal face cascade. I then pass these co-ordinates to Camshift (using the OpenCV example code) to track that face from that frame onwards. I'm then using Haar eye/mouth detection within the tracked box returned by Camshift, assuming that as my region of interest.

When I do this, the eye/mouth detection returns very few/no results.

If I just do a basic run through the video with the same eye and mouth detectors without Camshift, then they detect the eyes and mouth (although often detecting mouths as eyes and vice versa, but still much better detection than my Camshift-tracked ROI approach).

This is counter to my expectations - shouldn't limiting search within an ROI of a known and tracked face allow for much more reliable facial feature detection than if you do a dumb scan of the entire video frame? Perhaps I'm doing something inappropriate with my search co-ordinates…

Any help very much appreciated.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import cv
from common import clock, draw_str
import video

class App(object):

def __init__(self, video_src):  

    if video_src == "webcam":
        self.cam = video.create_capture(0)

    else:       
        self.vidFile = cv.CaptureFromFile('sources/' + video_src + '.mp4')
        self.vidFrames = int(cv.GetCaptureProperty(self.vidFile, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

    self.cascade_fn = "haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
    self.cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(self.cascade_fn)

    self.left_eye_fn = "haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml"
    self.left_eye = cv2.CascadeClassifier(self.left_eye_fn)

    self.mouth_fn = "haarcascades/haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml"
    self.mouth = cv2.CascadeClassifier(self.mouth_fn)       

    self.selection = None
    self.drag_start = None
    self.tracking_state = 0
    self.show_backproj = False

    self.face_frame = 0

    cv2.namedWindow('camshift')
    cv2.namedWindow('source')
    #cv2.namedWindow('hist')

    if video_src == "webcam":
        while True:
            ret, img = self.cam.read()
            self.rects = self.faceSearch(img)
            print "Searching for face..."
            if len(self.rects) != 0:
                break

    else:
        for f in xrange(self.vidFrames):
            img = cv.QueryFrame(self.vidFile)
            tmp = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img), 8, 3)
            cv.CvtColor(img, tmp, cv.CV_BGR2RGB)
            img = np.asarray(cv.GetMat(tmp))
            print "Searching frame", f+1
            self.face_frame = f
            self.rects = self.faceSearch(img)
            if len(self.rects) != 0:
                break

def faceSearch(self, img):

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)

    rects = self.detect(gray, self.cascade)

    if len(rects) != 0:
        print "Detected face"
        sizeX = rects[0][2] - rects[0][0]
        sizeY = rects[0][3] - rects[0][1]
        print "Face size is", sizeX, "by", sizeY
        return rects
    else:
        return []

def detect(self, img, cascade):

    # flags = cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
    rects = cascade.detectMultiScale(img, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=2, minSize=(80, 80), flags = cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE)
    if len(rects) == 0:
        return []
    rects[:,2:] += rects[:,:2]
    return rects

def draw_rects(self, img, rects, color):
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in rects:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color, 2)

def show_hist(self):
    bin_count = self.hist.shape[0]
    bin_w = 24
    img = np.zeros((256, bin_count*bin_w, 3), np.uint8)
    for i in xrange(bin_count):
        h = int(self.hist[i])
        cv2.rectangle(img, (i*bin_w+2, 255), ((i+1)*bin_w-2, 255-h), (int(180.0*i/bin_count), 255, 255), -1)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    cv2.imshow('hist', img)
    cv.MoveWindow('hist', 0, 440)

def faceTrack(self, img):
    vis = img.copy()        

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, np.array((0., 60., 32.)), np.array((180., 255., 255.)))

    x0, y0, x1, y1 = self.rects[0]
    self.track_window = (x0, y0, x1-x0, y1-y0)
    hsv_roi = hsv[y0:y1, x0:x1]
    mask_roi = mask[y0:y1, x0:x1]
    hist = cv2.calcHist( [hsv_roi], [0], mask_roi, [16], [0, 180] )
    cv2.normalize(hist, hist, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX);
    self.hist = hist.reshape(-1)
    #self.show_hist()

    vis_roi = vis[y0:y1, x0:x1]
    cv2.bitwise_not(vis_roi, vis_roi)
    vis[mask == 0] = 0

    prob = cv2.calcBackProject([hsv], [0], self.hist, [0, 180], 1)
    prob &= mask
    term_crit = ( cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 1 )
    track_box, self.track_window = cv2.CamShift(prob, self.track_window, term_crit)

    if self.show_backproj:
        vis[:] = prob[...,np.newaxis]
    try: cv2.ellipse(vis, track_box, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    except: print track_box     

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)

    xc = track_box[0][0]
    yc = track_box[0][1]

    xsize = track_box[1][0]
    ysize = track_box[1][1]

    x1 = int(xc - (xsize/2))
    y1 = int(yc - (ysize/2))
    x2 = int(xc + (xsize/2))
    y2 = int(yc + (ysize/2))

    roi_rect = y1, y2, x1, x2

    roi = gray[y1:y2, x1:x2]
    vis_roi = img.copy()[y1:y2, x1:x2]

    subrects_left_eye = self.detect(roi.copy(), self.left_eye)
    subrects_mouth = self.detect(roi.copy(), self.mouth)

    if subrects_left_eye != []:
        print "eye:", subrects_left_eye, "in roi:", roi_rect

    self.draw_rects(vis_roi, subrects_left_eye, (255, 0, 0))
    self.draw_rects(vis_roi, subrects_mouth, (0, 255, 0))

    cv2.imshow('test', vis_roi)

    dt = clock() - self.t
    draw_str(vis, (20, 20), 'time: %.1f ms' % (dt*1000))
    #draw_str(vis, (20, 35), 'frame: %d' % f)

    cv2.imshow('source', img)
    cv.MoveWindow('source', 500, 0)
    cv2.imshow('camshift', vis) 


def run(self):

    if video_src == "webcam":
        while True:
            self.t = clock()
            ret, img = self.cam.read()

            self.faceTrack(img)

            ch = 0xFF & cv2.waitKey(1)
            if ch == 27:
                break
            if ch == ord('b'):
                self.show_backproj = not self.show_backproj

    else:
        for f in xrange(self.face_frame, self.vidFrames):
            self.t = clock()
            img = cv.QueryFrame(self.vidFile)
            if type(img) != cv2.cv.iplimage:
                break

            tmp = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img), 8, 3)
            cv.CvtColor(img, tmp, cv.CV_BGR2RGB)
            img = np.asarray(cv.GetMat(tmp))    

            self.faceTrack(img)

            ch = 0xFF & cv2.waitKey(5)
            if ch == 27:
                break
            if ch == ord('b'):
                self.show_backproj = not self.show_backproj     

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    try: video_src = sys.argv[1]
    except: video_src = '1'
    App(video_src).run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned the minsize for detectMultiScale as 80 pixels. It might be true for the face but the eyes and mouth are not that big. So that might be one reason for not detecting eyes and mouth. Try reducing that to 20 or 30 pixels when calling for eyes and mouth.